# I have a Windows VPN Authentication issue even we configured Windows Authentication issue in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I have a Windows VPN Authentication issue even we configured Windows Authentication issue in JMeter.

[I provide the authentication details like username and Password but still not allow to login into application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24WB4.png)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some cookies required and header value that may be missing. Try with [cookie manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and [header manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in your test plan. Also, sniff the request with wireshark or any other sniffer and check the different header values send with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide at least your [Windows Domain](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-domain-name-command-line/) as well in the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager).

Depending on your application configuration you might also need to provide [NTLM Realm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944123(v=office.12).aspx)

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information regarding configuring JMeter in order to bypass [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) login challenge.

Comment: Thanks for Replay @Dmitri T
Do you know what exact detail we need to give for NTML as i already update jmeter.properties set httpclient4.auth.preemptive=false but still nothing is work